Is there a category even more general than "thing"?
Is there a category even more general than "thing"? Or is "thing" the most general category there is? That is, does there exist an x such that x is not a thing? Personally, I believe that "thing" is the most general category. But I would love to read what philosophers have written about this topic.

This question is a thing in itself.

Yes. It's always the universe of discourse the thing belongs to. If you have a thing, then you have the thing that contains the thing, be it language or container. Intuitionistic type theory allows an arbitrary expansion of the universe discourse, as well, so one universe can belong to a category more than general; that is universes can be nested ad nauseum.

I thinj @DavidGudeman's answer has it. The question seems more one of semantics than ontology or taxonomy. (But I don't mean pejoratively, as in "that's mere semantics". Your question is tugging on what is for me at leat an important thread.) I guess I could summarize like this: if the category "thing" turns out to be contained within a more general category called "thang" (say), then unless both are sufficiently well defined so as to carry useful semantic content, we could simply swap one for the other and we'd have lost nothing. Ergo, semantics.

Another example. In Ireland, there is a common slang word, "yoke"; it's similar in usage to words like "thingummyjig" or "whatchamacallit" etc. They're all pretty much synonyms for "thing". So if an Irishman points at something and asks, "What's that yoke there?" he's almost certainly asking you to tell him the name of the thing he is pointing at. Together, it suggests that when we cannot identify/name a...####...then we fall back on a catchall. Almost by definition, that catchall Just Is the most general category. (Note my use of #### to illustrate my very point -- we need a catchall.)

Isn't this an English language question?

Just want to say that I like how the question and many of the answers are very focused on how the question would be answered within the context of a particular philosopher/school/etc. in my view this is phil.se at its best.

Not all terms and descriptions refer to things. Given any ontology, there are terms and descriptions that do not refer to any element of the ontology. But "concept" covers all terms and descriptions.

@user107952, I think you got it right. Using simple logic and a dictionary --i.e. all the meanings of the word "thing"-- I cannot think of anything more general, i.e. that contains things. Of course, as always, people like to show off and bring up unnecessary and useless ... stuff into such cases! (BTW, I also like to use the word "stuff". Sometimes it fits better.)

What you regard as the most general category depends on your preferred understanding of epistemology and metaphysics. For Berkeley and Hume, 'idea' is the most general category. For Leibniz it is 'monad'. For process philosophers such as Whitehead, it is 'process'. For many of the logical positivists it is 'phenomena' - meaning the direct object of the senses. According to Wittgenstein in the Tractatus, the world is the totality of facts, not of things.
In Russell's version of logical atomism, 'things' are fundamental. The universe consists of things, and these things have properties and there are relations between things. This position, in one form or another, has come to be dominant in analytical philosophy. It is reflected in the way we do logic and corresponds pretty well to how scientists talk.
But it still leaves open various questions such as whether universals are things that exist in their own right, whether abstract objects such as numbers are things, whether minds are things, whether possible or potential entities should qualify as things, etc.

+1 So my summary of your post: If things sit in ontologies then ontologies sit in ???  ?

@Rushi: people.

David Loy wrote a book called, "The World Is Made Of Stories", so it would be the most general story. "In the beginning..."

@Rushi If things sit in ontologies then ontologies sit in ontologies, unless you're going to argue that ontologies aren't things.

@Rushi "Then ontologies it on..."  Turtles.  It's turtles all the way down.

@CortAmmon Um... Lets see: So for idealists its all in idea, for Leibniz-ian its in monad and Whitehead-ian in process etc, what is the (meta)ontology that contains all these ontologies? Can you even vaguely formulate what that is? (1/2)

@JimBalter I suspect its one of  (1) an analytical tautological meaningless definition such as «Since "everything" contains "thing" they are all things» (2) Some other wordplay (3) Something mystical/Eastern as implied by Scott Atman is it that projects and withdraws the whole universe into itself. I would certainly be curious if I missed a 4th possibility! (2/2)

@Rushi "I suspect its one of ..." you mean "it's" (or "it is") but I don't know what "it" refers to, or how your comment relates to mine. It's clear that if "thing" is the most general category then ontologies are things, and if things sit in ontologies then ontologies sit in ontologies. Of course one can question those "if"s ... I'm not asserting them.

@JimBalter Yeah It's it's not its — typo (or autocorrect). My 2 comments (1/2) and (2/2) need to be read together

@Rushi Ah yes; doh. An ontology is a set of those things that exist (in someone's view). So ontologies are things in an ontology of someone who considers abstract sets to be things that exist.

@Bumble
If there are varying and exclusive notions of the most fundamental, it implies not all capture the most fundamental.
I think that logically, to ask whether the most fundamental is the most fundamental ought to be illegitimate because it implies the possibility of it not being such. But for all these options it seems we CAN legitimately ask: "is process the most fundamental?" and the answer "No" be a possibility, which entails a distinction between "the most fundamental" and process. So it goes around. Except for aspects of the fundamental ideal categories like meaning, logic, etc

There isn't really a standard terminology although the word tends to be used that way. Philosophers typically use "object", "individual" or "particular" as the base sort of thing that exists or that can have properties or that can be predicated of or something like that. Those three words are largely interchangeable, although some philosophers prefer one and others prefer another. Based on how a philosopher defines object/individual/particular, there are sometimes arguments over whether anything isn't whatever that is, and for this purpose, the word "thing" is often used informally. But even then it's not always clear whether it is meant to be the most general category. Some philosophers don't even acknowledge the existence of a category that includes everything.

I think I agree, since you seem (?) to be saying that this is more a question of semantics than ontology. Your answer itself even demonstrates the problem, with the phrase "a category that included everything". Depending on how the word is used that very category could be considered a "thing", by virtue of you even naming it (cf. this). The bottom line is, if category "thing" were contained within category "superthing", then unless "thing" is precisely defined, it really is just semantics.

@tkp, yes, I took it as a question of philosophical terminology since the question doesn't define "thing".

Many things aren't objects.

@Rushi, the question had nothing to do with OOP. Why should my answer have brought in a completely unrelated topic?

At some point you have the problem of the category of all categories that aren't members of themselves....

@AlexanderWoo See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9896/category-of-all-categories-vs-set-of-all-sets

“Thing” includes everything physical or abstract. But it doesn’t give true picture of reality. From Buddhist point of view “phenomena” would be a more appropriate and all inclusive term.  It is interesting to note that , every “thing” is a “phenomena”.

If everything is a phenomenon then there is nothing that exists that is not perceptible by the human senses. I doubt Buddhism really holds that position.

Who said anything about reality? The most general category must include the non-real. As for the other comment, not all phenomena are perceptible by the human senses.

@JimBalter right, just ask a dog.

You can have noumena which are those things that are not phenomena, especially for Kantians or neo-Kantians...

@DoubleKnot There is nothing beyond six senses.. even God is perceptible through senses. This is a Buddhist position.

Then why not choose the category of the sensible/perceptible like Berkeley's to be is to be perceived under God's view? But then philosophers like Kant would argue the sensible has a clear meaningful possible negation which is unsensible for any particular finite being, and it seems OP isn't asking from God's view even if it really exists. Kant would also argue that sensibility like intelligibility needs other things like imagined intuitions...

@DoubleKnot phenomena means that which is perceptible is not static. It arises , changes and vanishes. Mind is also a sense organ. Intuition falls under the category of mind perception.

If intuition really powerlessly falls under your category of mind perception, then for a delusional or deviant person how Buddha could ever be possible to convert many of his disciples since such a person's category of perception could very well likely become full of confused or deviate perceptions? There was once a famous disciple who was so confused that he couldn't even remember one single proposition induced by phenomenal perceptions...

'Thing' isn't a proper category. 'Thing' is more like a gesture: a 'thing' is whatever one happens to (literally or metaphorically) point at. It's the same reason that 'he' is not a category.  'Male' is a category, because there are defined inclusion/exclusion rules; 'he' is a pointer to a particular member of the category 'male'. There's no abstract category that I can think of such that 'thing' points to one of its members. 'Thing' is essentially a generic universal pointer, along with others like 'stuff' and 'crap'.
I mean, I suppose I could argue that 'stuff' is more general than 'thing' because 'thing' is necessarily singular while 'stuff' can be collective… But if I did I don't think I'd respect myself in the morning.

"thing" is like "male" and (very) unlike "he".  There is a set of males and a set of things--the latter purportedly being the broadest set--it contains everything (aka every thing). "he' is a pointer to a particular member", no, quite the opposite--it's completely context-dependent.

@JimBalter: as I said, the category 'male' has distinct inclusion/exclusion criteria. That's what makes it a category. There are no such criteria for 'thing'. And yes, 'he' is a context-dependent pointer to a particular member of the category 'male', just like 'thing' is a context-dependent universal pointer.

I of course know what you said ... but it's obviously mistaken. Sorry, but some people just aren't very good at this, and I'm under no obligation to engage with them further. Over and out.

@JimBalter: Hah ! Works for me.

OP: Is there a category even more general than "thing"?
Indeed there is such a category: Being.  (In the quotes below, from Heidegger's Being & Time, things, or beings [Seiendes], are described as 'entities'.)

it has been maintained that 'Being' is the 'most universal'
concept: τὸ ὄν ἐστι καθόλου μάλιστα πάντων.i lllud quod
primo cadit sub apprehensione est ens, cuius intellectus includitur in
omnibus, quaecumque quis apprehendit. 'An understanding of Being is
already included in conceiving anything which one apprehends as an
entity.'1, ii GA 2, H.
3
i. (H. 3) Aristotle, Metaphysica B 4, 1001 a
21.
"for Unity and Being are the most universal of all terms"
ii. (H. 3 ) Thomas Aquinas, Summa Theologica 1-11 Q. 94 art.
2.
"The first thing to fall within apprehension is being, a grasp of
which is included in everything that anyone apprehends"

The word 'Seiendes', which Heidegger uses in his paraphrase, is one of the most important words in the book. The substantive 'das Seiende'
is derived from the participle 'seiend' (see note 1, p. 19), and means
literally 'that which is'; 'ein Seiendes' means 'something which is'.
There is much to be said for translating 'Seiendes' by the noun
'being' or 'beings' (for it is often used in a collective sense). We
feel, however, that it is smoother and less confusing to write
'entity' or 'entities'.



In the question which we are to work out, what is asked about is
Being­—that which determines entities as entities, that on the basis
of which [woraufhin] entities are already understood, however we may
discuss them in detail. The Being of entities 'is' not itself an
entity. If we are to understand the problem of Being, our first
philosophical step consists in not μῦθόν τινα διηγεῖσθαιv
in not 'telling a story'—that is to say, in not defining entities as
entities by tracing them back in their origin to some other entities,
as if Being had the character of some possible entity. Hence Being, as
that which is asked about, must be exhibited in a way of its own,
essentially different from the way in which entities are discovered.
Accordingly, what is to be found out by the asking—the meaning of
Being—also demands that it be conceived in a way of its own,
essentially contrasting with the concepts in which entities acquire
their determinate signification. GA 2, H.
6
v. (H. 6) Plato, Sophistes
242c.


But couldn't Heidegger's "Being" itself be considered a "thing", at least as the latter word  is normally used? For example, he himself quotes Aquinas, presumably by way of illustration, treating "being" as a thing, specifically: "The first thing to fall within apprehension" (emphasis mine).

@tkp No, it is necessarily not a thing, in order not to be simply 'telling stories' about things that originate other things. i.e. "The Being of entities 'is' not itself an entity [a thing]." (The verb 'is' is in quotes to acknowledge the limitation of language in talking about being, since the infinitive "to be" is a verbal substantive.)

Hmm. If you're referring to something akin to, say, the Thomist distinction between being and "a being" then I might be understanding you. So, a theist of the "classical" persuasion (and of sufficient philosophical sophistication) might answer the question "Does God exist", with "No. God is existence" (or something like that). Is there any mileage in that? Regardless, I'm saying that in the normal use of the word "thing", it covers...well, everything. That is, you name it, it's a thing, simply because that's how "thing" is used.

@tkp They're pointing at the same place, but Heidegger takes it somewhere different, e.g. "the aim of the existential analytic can be made plainer by considering Descartes, who is credited with providing the point of departure for modern philosophical inquiry by his discovery of the "cogito sum". He investigates the "cogitare" of the "ego", at least within certain limits. On the other hand, he leaves the "sum" completely undiscussed, even though it is regarded as no less primordial than the cogito." GA 2, H. 46

Thanks. Interesting site. Yours?

@tkp Nope. There’s a pretty good group on Facebook too: Heidegger Forum 2024

In the perennial tradition (originating with Plato and continuing through Augustine to Thomas to the present), thing is not a category, properly speaking. A category divides beings into different, shall we say, classes such that if a being belongs in one category then it may or may not be in another category. Thing, on the other hand, is called a transcendental because it transcends any such category of being. It is, so to speak, transcategorical and applies to every being necessarily. To stretch the expressive capabilities of language a little bit, it is absolutely necessary to say that anything and everything is necessarily a thing.
There is, in fact, more than one transcendental. There are the famous ones such as being, one, good, truth, beauty, and the not so famous ones such as thing and something (Latin aliquid) etc. (There may, in fact, be others that I can't recall at the moment since I am currently writing this off the top of my head. I may edit this later just to fill in citations.)
All of the transcendentals can be predicated of any and every being. Thus we say that they "extend" to every being or that they are equal in extension. In this sense, they are equally general. That in which they differ is their conception. To illustrate, the most general thing we can say about anything is that it is (Latin est from esse). Period. Full stop. Before we can say anything else, it first must be. In this sense, being is the most general. (I do not say exists because being and existence are not the same. How exactly they differ is a totally different question...)
But we can next notice, that a being is not many beings. It is a singular being. It is "undivided". Thus we arrive at a notion of one. Again we can see that a being is of a certain kind, for example, a human-being. That is, it has an essence or nature. Thus we arrive at a notion of thing. (This is precisely what thing is: being as specified by essence). And this is precisely why thing is a transcendental: because anything and everything has to be some kind of being (reread the previous paragraph, especially the bold, if this isn't obvious yet).
Similarly, for the other transcendentals we can specify a relation on being. For example, truth is being related to intellect, good is being related to will (or desire), etc. Something is a peculiar one in that it is precisely a relation of one being to other (distinct) beings.
Much, much more could be said about the transcendentals, but I think this sufficiently answers the OP.

Illustrative remark: observe that one of the first things (and sometimes the only thing) that a mathematician can prove about a mathematical object is that it exists.

Mathematicians don't prove that objects exist, they prove that sets aren't empty: "there exists an x such that " means that the set of things with that description isn't empty. This "exists" isn't even ontological, it's  an abstract inference from a set of formal axioms.

@JimBalter An abstract inference is a movement of reason, and an existence theorem proves whether a mathematical object exists. Here I understand existing as "being according to the mode proper to the object under consideration" which is here specifically mathematical objects. Ontology comes from the Greek ontos (being) and logos (word, concept, reason). I fail to understand how an existence theorem is not ontological. Perhaps there is an equivocation on "existing"?


Is there a category even more general than "thing"? Or is "thing" the most general category there is?


Thing is the most general category, according to someone with a normal psychology.

In naive set theory the following statement is true.

∀x[x ∈ U]

The symbol x is a variable, and the symbol U is a constant.  Using the natural language of English, the meaning of the statement is that the set denoted by U contains every thing. Thus we can establish the following
Definition
X denotes a thing iff X ∈U
The set denoted by U can be proved unique, and is called the supremum genus, or the universal set.
Any set theory which precludes the existence/subsistence of the universal set is simply wrong.
Definitions
X is a compound statement iff there are statements A,B such that[A ≠ B and X = (A and B) or X = not(A and B)
X is a simple statement iff X is not compound.
Predicate Constants
In logic, any simple statement contains exactly one predicate constant.
In FOL we postulate an infinite number of 0-ary predicate constants, each of which is intended to be a simple statement.
For example, consider the simple statement
The sun is hot.
There is a 0-ary predicate constant, say A0, equivalent to the English statement.  Thus
A0 = The sun is hot.
Attributes are represented by unary predicate constants.  Thus the attribute of 'being hot', can be represented by the predicate constant
A1
We can form the propositional function of a single individual variable
A1(x)
So if s represents the sun, we can say
A0 = A1(s) = The sun is hot.
For a more complex example consider the simple statement
Jack sold his cow to the peddler for a bag of beans.
It is an instance of the propositional function 'x sold y to z for w' and can be symbolized as
A4(x,y,z,w)
It is clear that any instance of A4(x,y,z,w), is not a compound statement. Here, the symbol A4 designates a particular quaternary relation.
In higher order logic, you can quantify over individuals and predicates.  So every thing that can be pondered using higher order logic is either an individual or a predicate.  If we let I denote the set of individuals, and I' denote the set of non-individuals, then
U= I ⋃ I'
and
I ⋂ I' = ∅
As far as higher order logic is concerned, every thing that isn't an individual is a predicate.  So let P denote the set of predicates.  Then
I' = P
From Wikipedia

Up to a certain notion of isomorphism, the powerset operation is definable in second-order logic. Using this observation, Jaakko Hintikka established in 1955 that second-order logic can simulate higher-order logics in the sense that for every formula of a higher-order logic, one can find an equisatisfiable formula for it in second-order logic.


First-order logic quantifies only variables that range over individuals; second-order logic, also quantifies over sets; third-order logic also quantifies over sets of sets, and so on.

Consider the statement
"1 ∈N."
It's an instance of the propositional function A2(x,y), where A2 designates a particular binary relation. Here, we are faced with a question.  What kind of things can be instantiated for the variables x, and y? It is customary in first order logic, to restrict the domain of all variables to individuals, and to differentiate between individuals and sets. I prefer to treat a set as a kind of individual.  Thus, in the expression A2(x,y), the variables x,y denote individuals, and the symbol A2 denotes the binary predicate constant "is an element of".  By treating sets as a kind of individual, we can use FOL to discuss set theory, and we don't have to formulate new symbolism for the notion of a well formed formula.
Since predicates and individuals are kinds of things, inasmuch as 'thing' is the most general category, we can refer to the most general logic, and call it General Order Logic.  All quantified variables must be instantiated by constants that denote things.  So there is no need to specify the domain of discourse, it's necessarily U.
From Wikipedia

The term predicate is used in two ways in linguistics and its subfields. The first defines a predicate as everything in a standard declarative sentence except the subject, and the other defines it as only the main content verb or associated predicative expression of a clause. Thus, by the first definition, the predicate of the sentence Frank likes cake is likes cake, while by the second definition, it is only the content verb likes, and Frank and cake are the arguments of this predicate. The conflict between these two definitions can lead to confusion.

From this site we find

Aristotle’s Categories is an ontological piece attempting to differentiate between states of being. It is a short piece, broken up into fifteen chapters. The most basic component is the distinction between the subject and the predicate. The former is what the statement is about; the latter is what is describes.


The question itself is somewhat vague. What is a category ? What is a thing ?
And then the answer will depend on your epistemology and metaphysics, as Bumble already observed.
To the various philosophical viewpoints that are recalled, I would like to add briefly to the discussion the viewpoints of Arthur Schopenhauer, Karl Jaspers and Maurice Merleau-Ponty. All of them would object to Russell's atomism (even though Russell's claim is primarily restricted to logics) but on different grounds. Hence it seems to me that all of them would answer negatively to the question. [And of course, Schopenhauer died before Russell was born, so the conditional/conjectural form "would" applies especially to him.]
Schopenhauer would contest that thing is the most general category not because it is not the most encompassing category but because, as he is famously known to have claimed, there is no object without subject and no subject without object. Since a thing for Schopenhauer is nothing without the knowing subject exercising his will, it is fair to say that he would not include thing as the most general category.
According to Jaspers, if the goal of metaphysics is to answer the question "what is being as being ?", all answers that pertain to atomism like water (Thales), fire, atom, spirit, etc., while venerable, are inadequate when they claim to be the unique answer. All these conceptions share the common idea that something inside reality and outside of myself is the source of all the rest. Against this, he claims that being cannot be neither an object nor a subject but "das Umgreifende" that manifests itself in the scission object-subject.
As a phenomenologist, Merleau-Ponty would say that the world is not a "thing" (and not even a "big" thing) because man does not sejourn in a "thing" but in the world.

There is a more general category:  the Tao.  ...Or something like that.  Break down the unity of the Tao, and you have yang (things) and yin (flows).  And "from two begot three, and from three the ten thousand things..." [Tao Te Ching, verse 42]
